# Cancel out a Sum(value) in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression

I have a group in a tablix in SSRS.  The Group has fields as follows

```
Member,
NonMember,
Student,
Intern,
Cancelled
```

What I want to do is Eliminate the count of the Cancelled from the `SUM(Groups)`.

I've tried this

```
=SUM(IIF (Field!Group.Value = "Member" or Field!Group.Value = "Nonmember" or Fields!Group.Value = "Student" or Fields!Group.Value = "Intern",Fields!Units.Value,Nothing),DataSet1)
```

Here is an image of the report
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was the ,DataSet1) at the end.  I dropped that off and the calculation worked as it should.